# How to pass the two digit 'state code' or 'state name' in Azure-Maps Get Search Address API?

Tags: azure-maps

I am not able to pass the two digit 'state code' or full state name in Azure-Maps Get Search Address API

I tried by passing the two digit 'state code' in 'query' parameter of  Azure-Maps Get Search Address API. But want to pass two digit 'state code' as separate parameter like 'countrySubdivision'

https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key={subscription-key}&countrySet=US&query=WA+US

I am expecting to pass 'countrySubdivision' parameter to Azure-Maps Get Search Address API, like below
https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/json?api-version=1.0&subscription-key={subscription-key}&countrySet=US&countrySubdivision=WA

Answer (score 0):

The [Azure Maps Search Address **Structured** API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddressstructured) allows you to specify the `countrySubdivision` (state/province) as part of the request.

Example query:

GET `https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/structured/{format}?subscription-key={subscription-key}&api-version=1.0&language={language}&countryCode={countryCode}&countryTertiarySubdivision={countryTertiarySubdivision}&countrySecondarySubdivision={countrySecondarySubdivision}&countrySubdivision={countrySubdivision}`

Give it a try and see if it's helpful.